# Can cell addresses (vs. cell contents) be used as operands in Excel formulae?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Consider the following scenario illustrating the data I have vs. the data I want. Very simply, I have a single column that represents Field 1, Contents of Field 1,...etc. and is more appropriately formatted as pairs of rows across columns.

[image]     [image]

I've been experimenting with the `TRANSPOSE` function, but that one's new to me and I'm not sure it's the right direction. At first glance, it doesn't seem to accomodate my needs. But I could be wrong...

While it would be relatively simple to set up an 'every other row' formula, I also have to account for situations where I may have a `foo` repeating with a single `bar` or vice versa, and that's where I'm stuck. What I need is a "next unused cell" function, or something that can add X rows or Y columns to a particular cell.

I can envision a formula that can manipulate the cell *label* and solve my problem: 
`=($A1+2rows)` or some kind of `=$(A+3)$(4+2)` that would return cell `D6`.

Is something like that possible?

Comment: Check out the `INDEX` function. This will allow you to flexibly return a value. Alternatively, `INDIRECT` and `OFFSET` will also be useful!

Comment: +1 for `OFFSET`; it's _exactly_ what I was looking for. I don't suppose there's a `PULLESPRESSO(numberOfShots,lengthOfPull)` function somewhere...I'm stating to think that Excel can do EVERYTHING!

Comment: LOL! Check out the INDEX function though - it is equivalent to OFFSET in many ways, but more efficient - see my answer below. If it solved your problem, please mark it as the answer! Thx

Comment: If you just wanted to flip from rows/columns you could use the steps here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/switch-transpose-columns-and-rows-HP010224502.aspx?CTT=3. Give that you want to move some cells one way and others another Peter's examples work better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three functions you can use for your scenario:

**OFFSET**

Using `=OFFSET($A$1,NumberOfRows,NumberOfCols)`, you can bascially shift the reference to cell A1 in any direction.
Pros: Easy to use; can also be used to create a range of multiple cells (e.g. in dynamic names), using fourth&fifth parameter
Cons: Volatile, i.e. Excel will recalc formula every time

**INDIRECT** combined with **ADDRESS**

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(RowNum,ColNum,,,Sheetname))` will allow you to access any cell in Sheetname. (If you leave out sheetname, it'll work use the current worksheet.
Pro: Can handle multiple workhsheets
Con: Volalite, can't handle other workbooks unless opened

**INDEX**

`=INDEX($A:$Z,RowNum,ColNum)`
Pro: Non-Volatile, i.e. will not slow down recalcs in large models; very versatile (e.g. in combination with MATCH)
Cons: Array needs to be specified up front

Personally, I always try to use `INDEX`, only on occasions using `INDIRECT`(basically when the sheet name needs to be dynamic) - and almost never `OFFSET`...